# Heegner Prime visualizations

Tags: complex-numbers, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

The [Heegner numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number) are 1, 2, 3, 7, 11, 19, 43, 67, 163. The ring of integers $\textbf{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ have unique factorizations.
1 gives the [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer).
3 gives the [Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer).
7 gives the [Kleinian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleinian_integer).

What happened to 2, 11, 19, and the others?  Here are pictures of the primes for 1, 2, 3, 7.

[image: Heegner primes]

Comment: Mathematica, and I basically used a complex number version of the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: What happened is that a lot of professional mathematicians consider literal numbers to be beneath them. At least with $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, this evil is mitigated by the fact that the lattice shapes are equilateral, and therefore more elegant than in the other domains.

Comment: Also, there are practical considerations. By the time you get to $d = 163$, each purely real integer is $\sqrt{41}$ away from the nearest complex integer in the domain.

Answer (score 5):

I've decided to call $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$ the [Hippasus integers](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/965609), after Hippasus, who was murdered for proving $\sqrt{2}$'s irrationality.

Comment: I like this idea lmao. I’ll start using it when I can. Do you want to say instead the Hipassus Rationals and Hippasus integers?